# My SQL SELECT STATEMENT returns an empty table instead of an error

Tags: mysql, sql

My SELECT count function returns the number of kids in a specific profile that has in id (secte = id_profile). When I input an invalid profile, the select statement returns an empty table insead of an error that I can solve. Any tips? (The tables are created by me);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bursieri(sectie profile.id_profile%type)
return number IS
numar number(3) := 0;
BEGIN
select count(s.first_name) into numar
from student s, profile p,class c
where s.id_class = c.id_class and c.id_profile = p.id_profile
and p.id_profile=sectie;
return numar;
END bursieri;

/
--profilul 71

BEGIN   
dbms_output.put_line('Exista ' || bursieri(9100) || ' studenti bursieri');
END;
```

I tried to give an invalid profile id and expected an error, but instead I got an empty table

Comment: Oh I unterstand. So, how can I edit that select so it returns an exception sometimes?

Comment: You can consider raising a [signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) when the function returns an empty result set (`COUNT(*) = 0`).

Comment: I need to treat Exceptions, that is my exercise for school

Comment: Are you sure that you use MySQL? The code looks like OracleDB one..